# Sub menu have to appear at the starting point as above div

Tags: html, css

Here is my code in [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/b5b8t/19/)

Here i have a demo div, If i select the menu product it should always select the sub menu starting like the **above Demo div's start Point**.

Here is my code.

**CSS code for the sub menu:**

```
ul li ul {
display: none;
width: 300px;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
margin-left: 8px;
}
```

Did i missed anything in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ul{
    position: relative;
}
ul li ul{
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/b5b8t/21/)

Answer (score 1):

```
ul li{
   float: left;
   width: 100px;
   text-align: center;
   position:relative; <---- add this
}
```

`position:relative` sets the origin point for absolutely-positioned child elements.

Answer (score 1):

When  you write `position:absolute` it take position relative to your browser window ,try `position:relative` whic takes position relative to its parent

```
ul li ul {
display: none;
width: 300px;
position: relative;
left: 0;
margin-left: 0px;
}
```